# Issues trying to install SignalR

Tags: nuget

Im having trouble trying to install the SignalR package, I use the command

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

but I get an error saying:

> Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'

Error that appears
[image]

I have tried to use the nuget package manager as apposed to the console but it says it cannot find any results for 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Please help..

Comment: Usually the Nuget package manager in Visual Studio starts on the "Installed" pane, which shows the packages that are already installed in your project. Make sure you switch to "Browse" (just above the search box), so that it searches for SignalR package online.

Comment: There is no 'Browse' box or trick box, just 'Include Prerealease' which I have tried..

Comment: I have the choice between "Browse", "Installed" and "Updates". [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4UX7.png) from one of my projects, using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I tried clicking Browse and I still don't get any results back..

Comment: What is your "Package source" (top right, in the screenshot) set to? Make sure it is set to _"nuget.org"_ or simply _"All"_.

Comment: The drop box for it is empty I can't select 'nuget.org'

Comment: That sounds really strange. Try clicking the icon next to the dropdown menu which brings you to the Options for the package manager. Here you have the possibility to add different sources to search for Nuget packages, including _"nuget.org"_. [Here's a screenshot of my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNsAx.png).

Comment: I went into the settings and there still is nothing else I could select :(

Comment: Is _"nuget.org"_ on the list? If not, add it manually, using the settings in my screenshot, and make sure its checkbox is checked. Alternatively, check the _"Microsoft and .NET"_ option in the "Machine-wide package" section - this option should enable you to search for Microsoft-curated nuget packages, which includes SignalR.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? :-)

Comment: Fixed it, I had to go delete a temp nuget config file in app data / roaming / nuget, after I deleted it things seems to search on nuget and return results and was able to install signalR.